# JQuery Dialog that calls remote script via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I'm trying to get JQuery's dialog to send data to a remote script whenever the 'Add' Button is clicked in the dialog button, but my script seems to die at the .ajax and nothing is showing up in my console to give me a clue as to the error:

```
$( "#button" ).dialog({
  resizable: false,
  title: "Confirm",
  height:140,
  modal: true,
  autoOpen: false,
  buttons: {
    "Add": function() {
      var data = $('.part1').serialize()
      $.ajax({
          url: "/www/htdocs/test.pl",
          type: "GET",
          data: data,
          cache: false,
          success: function {
                   $('#div1').fadeOut('slow');
                   $('#div2').fadeIn('slow');
          }
      });     
      return false;
    },
    Cancel: function() {
      $(this).dialog( "close" );
    }
  }
});

<div id="div1">
<input class="part1" type="hidden" value="Jon" name="fname">
<input class="part1" type="hidden" value="Doe" name="lname">
<input class="part1" type="hidden" value="jon@doe.com" name="email">
<input id="button" type="button" value="button">
</div>
<div id="div2">Complete</div>
```

Comment: Try to add after the success function an error function. Like this: error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ console.log(textStatus);}. What the console is displaying?

Comment: And try add a ";" after var data = $('.part1').serialize()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a few syntax errors (which do show up in FireBug):

Add `;` at the end of:

`var data = $('.part1').serialize()`

like:

`var data = $('.part1').serialize();`

Add `()` after `success: function`

like:

`success: function()`

Making the full code like this:

```
$( "#button" ).dialog({
  resizable: false,
  title: "Confirm",
  height:140,
  modal: true,
  autoOpen: false,
  buttons: {
    "Add": function() {
      var data = $('.part1').serialize();
      $.ajax({
          url: "/www/htdocs/test.pl",
          type: "GET",
          data: data,
          cache: false,
          success: function()
          {
                   $('#div1').fadeOut('slow');
                   $('#div2').fadeIn('slow');
          }
      });     
      return false;
    },
    Cancel: function() {
      $(this).dialog( "close" );
    }
  }
});
```

with those fixes, working fine here:
http://jsfiddle.net/YzhG9/10/